# Pose Estimation - cv::SolvePnP with Scenekit - Coordinate System Question

Tags: opencv, opengl, computer-vision, scenekit, opencv-solvepnp

I have been working on Pose Estimation (rectifying key points on a 3D model with 2D points on an image to match pose) via OpenCV's cv::solvePNP, using features / key points from Apples Vision framework.

***TL-DR:***

My scene kit model is being translated and the units look correct when introspecting the translation and rotation vectors from solvePnP (ie, they are the right order of magnitude), but the coordinate system of the translation appears off:

[image: Example of attempt at pose estimation]

I am trying to understand the coordinate system requirements with solvePnP wrt to Metal / OpenGL coordinate system and my camera projection matrix.

What 'projectionMatrix' does my SCNCamera require to match image based coordinate system passed into solvePnP?

Some things ive read / believe I am taking into account.

- OpenCV vs OpenGL (thus Metal) have row major vs column major differences.
- OpenCV's coordinate system for 3D is different than OpenGL (thus Metal).

***Longer with code:***

My workflow is as such:

Step 1 - use a 3D model tool to introspect points on my 3D model and get the objects vertex positions for the major key points in the 2D detected features. I am using left pupil, right pupil, tip of nose, tip of chin, left outer lip corner, right outer lip corner.

Step 2 - Run a vision request and extract a list of points in image space (converting for OpenCV's top left coordinate system) and extract the same ordered list of 2D points.

Step 3 - Construct a camera matrix by using the size of the input image.

Step 4 - run cv::solvePnP, and then use cv::Rodrigues to convert the rotation vector to a matrix

Step 5 - Convert the coordinate system of the resulting transforms into something appropriate for the GPU - invert the y and z axis and combine the translation and rotation to a single 4x4 Matrix, and then transpose it for the appropriate major ness of OpenGL / Metal

Step 6 -  apply the resulting transform to Scenekit via:

```
        let faceNodeTransform = openCVWrapper.transform(for: landmarks, imageSize: size)
        self.destinationView.pointOfView?.transform = SCNMatrix4Invert(faceNodeTransform)
```

Below is my Obj-C++ OpenCV Wrapper which takes in a subset of Vision Landmarks and the true pixel size of the image being looked at:

```
/ https://answers.opencv.org/question/23089/opencv-opengl-proper-camera-pose-using-solvepnp/
- (SCNMatrix4) transformFor:(VNFaceLandmarks2D*)landmarks imageSize:(CGSize)imageSize
{
    // 1 convert landmarks to image points in image space (pixels) to vector of cv::Point2f's : 
    // Note that this translates the point coordinate system to be top left oriented for OpenCV's image coordinates:
    std::vector<cv::Point2f >  imagePoints = [self imagePointsForLandmarks:landmarks imageSize:imageSize];

    // 2 Load Model Points
    std::vector<cv::Point3f >  modelPoints = [self modelPoints];

    // 3 create our camera extrinsic matrix
    // TODO - see if this is sane?
    double max_d = fmax(imageSize.width, imageSize.height);
    cv::Mat cameraMatrix = (cv::Mat_<double>(3,3) << max_d, 0, imageSize.width/2.0,
                 0,    max_d, imageSize.height/2.0,
                 0,    0,    1.0);

    // 4 Run solvePnP
    double distanceCoef[] = {0,0,0,0};
    cv::Mat distanceCoefMat = cv::Mat(1 ,4 ,CV_64FC1,distanceCoef);

    // Output Matrixes
    std::vector<double> rv(3);
    cv::Mat rotationOut = cv::Mat(rv);

    std::vector<double> tv(3);
    cv::Mat translationOut = cv::Mat(tv);

    cv::solvePnP(modelPoints, imagePoints, cameraMatrix, distanceCoefMat, rotationOut, translationOut, false, cv::SOLVEPNP_EPNP);

    // 5 Convert rotation matrix (actually a vector)
    // To a real 4x4 rotation matrix:
    cv::Mat viewMatrix = cv::Mat::zeros(4, 4, CV_64FC1);
    cv::Mat rotation;
    cv::Rodrigues(rotationOut, rotation);

    // Append our transforms to our matrix and set final to identity:
    for(unsigned int row=0; row<3; ++row)
    {
        for(unsigned int col=0; col<3; ++col)
        {
            viewMatrix.at<double>(row, col) = rotation.at<double>(row, col);
        }
        viewMatrix.at<double>(row, 3) = translationOut.at<double>(row, 0);
    }

    viewMatrix.at<double>(3, 3) = 1.0f;

    // Transpose OpenCV to OpenGL coords
    cv::Mat cvToGl = cv::Mat::zeros(4, 4, CV_64FC1);
    cvToGl.at<double>(0, 0) = 1.0f;
    cvToGl.at<double>(1, 1) = -1.0f; // Invert the y axis
    cvToGl.at<double>(2, 2) = -1.0f; // invert the z axis
    cvToGl.at<double>(3, 3) = 1.0f;
    viewMatrix = cvToGl * viewMatrix;

    // Finally transpose to get correct SCN / OpenGL Matrix :
    cv::Mat glViewMatrix = cv::Mat::zeros(4, 4, CV_64FC1);
    cv::transpose(viewMatrix , glViewMatrix);

    return [self convertCVMatToMatrix4:glViewMatrix];
}

- (SCNMatrix4) convertCVMatToMatrix4:(cv::Mat)matrix
{
    SCNMatrix4 scnMatrix = SCNMatrix4Identity;

    scnMatrix.m11 = matrix.at<double>(0, 0);
    scnMatrix.m12 = matrix.at<double>(0, 1);
    scnMatrix.m13 = matrix.at<double>(0, 2);
    scnMatrix.m14 = matrix.at<double>(0, 3);

    scnMatrix.m21 = matrix.at<double>(1, 0);
    scnMatrix.m22 = matrix.at<double>(1, 1);
    scnMatrix.m23 = matrix.at<double>(1, 2);
    scnMatrix.m24 = matrix.at<double>(1, 3);

    scnMatrix.m31 = matrix.at<double>(2, 0);
    scnMatrix.m32 = matrix.at<double>(2, 1);
    scnMatrix.m33 = matrix.at<double>(2, 2);
    scnMatrix.m34 = matrix.at<double>(2, 3);

    scnMatrix.m41 = matrix.at<double>(3, 0);
    scnMatrix.m42 = matrix.at<double>(3, 1);
    scnMatrix.m43 = matrix.at<double>(3, 2);
    scnMatrix.m44 = matrix.at<double>(3, 3);

    return (scnMatrix);
}
```

Some questions:

- An SCNNode has no modelViewMatrix (just as I understand it, a transform, which is the modelMatrix) to just throw a matrix at - so I've read the inverse of the transform from SolvePNP process can be used to pose the camera instead, which appears to get me the closes result. I want to ensure this approach is correct.
- If I have the modelViewMatrix, and the projectionMatrix, I should be able to calculate the appropriate modelMatrix? Is this the approach I should be taking?
- Its unclear to me what projectionMatrix I should be using for my SceneKit Scene and If that has any bearing on my results. Do I need a pixel for pixel exact match of my viewport to the image size, and how do I properly configure my SCNCamera to ensure coordinate system agreeance for SolvePnP?

Thank you very much!